# Append Python Dictionary Values

Tags: python-3.x, list

I have the following code that creates an SQL statement via my `column` dictionary.

```
sql = 'UPDATE table SET {}'.format(', '.join('{} = %s'.format(k) for k in column))
cursor.execute(sql, list(column.values()))
```

My problem is I'm trying to include a value that is not in my dictionary, in a way that still protects me from SQL injections.

This line doesn't work:

```
sql = 'UPDATE table SET {} WHERE id = %s'.format(', '.join('{} = %s'.format(k) for k in column))
cursor.execute(sql, list(column.values()).append(url))
```

But this clunky line does:

```
sql = 'UPDATE table SET {} WHERE id = %s'.format(', '.join('{} = %s'.format(k) for k in column))
values = list(column.values())
values.append(url)
cursor.execute(sql, values)
```

I'd prefer to use the less clunky version. Is there a way I can cleanly append dictionary values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`list.append()` updates the list in-place and it does not return any value, so you are getting there `None` instead of the "list + one extra value" as you intend.

You can add two lists together instead:

```
list(column.values()) + [url]
```